# wildfly:deploy-artifact with downloaded artifact from command line

Tags: maven-3, wildfly-8

I am trying to deploy a downloaded war file using the `deploy-artifact` goal in Wildfly. I would like to do this from the command line.

I am getting the following error

> ```
> deploy-artifact must specify the artifactId
> ```

I have added the wildfly details to the `pom.xml` and tried to run following command:

```
mvn wildfly:deploy-artifact -DtargetDir=${project.build.directory}
-DartifactId=artifact-name
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this goal is not intended to be used from the command line since it requires the artifact to be a dependency of the project. The [goal documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-artifact-mojo.html) doesn't state any user property for the artifactId or groupId parameters so these are only settable in the configuration section of the plugin. I'm also struggling with our test setup and deployment of artifacts from our maven repo. But if you have already downloaded the artifact why don't you just use the cli to deploy it?

Comment: Yes there is no possibility to add the dependency of the project through command line. I am using CI server and my deployment happens through the CI server. Hence I am not using CLI to deploy, but now trying the deployment through Wildfly HTTP API